# TypeError: Embed.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Title'

Tags: python, discord

Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def help_mod(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(Title = 'Список команд бота')

    emb.add_field(name = '{}clear'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Очистка чата от сообщений')
    emb.add_field(name = '{}kick'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Удаление игрока из сервера')
    emb.add_field(name = '{}ban'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Ограничение доступа игрока к серверу')
    emb.add_field(name = '{}unban'.format(PREFIX), value = 'Удаление ограничение доступа игрока к серверу')

    emb.set_author(name = bot.user.name, icon_url = bot.user.avatar)

    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Embed.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Title'
```

Comment: параметр у `discord.Embed` называется `title`, а не `Title`